# HTTP error 403 in Python 3 web scraping the publications

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping, nlp

This is the traceback of the error that is happening when I am trying to put the URL of the publication. It works for the regular websites such as Stack Overflow or Wikipedia, but when I try it on the publications such as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1388248120302113?via%3Dihub, The error shows up.

Here is my code:

```py
req = Request(' https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1388248120302113?via%3Dihub', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_plain = urlopen(req).read()
```

Here is the traceback of the error:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response       
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default  
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
This is not an error in the code, this is the website refusing to server that page when you are doing the web **scraping**.

Comment: Some website just forbid that kind of request when the agent is not correct. There is actually a way to go around this since you can access the website with a browser

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    # If you're getting a 403 response, use this. ("HTTP error occurred: 403 Client Error: Forbidden")
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
    # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
else:
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).